# PHP - If key exists in a multidimensional associative array, return its position

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional associative array. The top level keys are numbers and the associative arrays inside have strings for both keys and values.

Here is an example of the array dump:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [AC21T12-M01] => 54318
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [AC03T11-F01] => 54480
        )

)
```

So I want to search for 'AC03T11-F01' and return 2 as the key position.

I tried `array_search('AC03T11-F01', $array);` but it didn't return anything so I'm guessing it's not a straightforward as I thought.

I've used the function below to key the key position when searching for a value, so maybe that could be adapted to search for keys too?

```
function getParentStack($child, $stack) {
    foreach ($stack as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            // If the current element of the array is an array, recurse it and capture the return
            $return = getParentStack($child, $v);

            // If the return is an array, stack it and return it
            if (is_array($return)) {
                //return array($k => $return);
                return $k;
            }
        } else {
            // Since we are not on an array, compare directly
            if ($v == $child) {
                // And if we match, stack it and return it
                return array($k => $child);
            }
        }
    }

    // Return false since there was nothing found
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$search = 'AC03T11-F01';
$found =  false;

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($value[$search])) {
        $found = $key;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now check `$found`.

Comment: Thanks @AbraCadaver. That worked perfectly and only a few lines. Perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

You might filter your array and then request keys:

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function(item) {
  return item === 'AC03T11-F01'
});

var_dump( array_keys( $filtered ) );
//⇒ [ 2 ]
```

Whether you want to retrieve the key of the first occurence:

```
$keys = array_keys( array_filter($array, function(item) {
  return item === 'AC03T11-F01'
}));
echo ($key = count( $keys ) > 0 ? $keys[0] : null);
//⇒ 2
```

Comment: This does not return a single key as OP requested

Comment: @Kleskowy Updated an answer.

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa. I've accepted AbraCadaver's answer, but I appreciate yours too :)